# How to order table using the row number and another field

Tags: sql

I need to order a table by using the row number and also with another field. 
my query is:

```
SELECT rownum,a.hospitalnumber,a.patientid,a.admissiondate, a.patientname,c.age,c.gender,a.icdcode,b.shortname, d.unitname 
FROM icdledger a,departmentmast b,registration c,inpatient d 
WHERE a.departmentcode=b.departmentcode 
   AND a.hospitalnumber=c.hospitalnumber 
   AND a.hospitalnumber=d.hospitalnumber 
   AND a.admissiondate>=TO_DATE('01/APR/2015') 
   AND a.admissiondate<=TO_DATE('16/APR/2015') 
   AND a.icdcode='Z38.0' 
   AND b.departmentname='PAEDIATRICS'
```

How to order by using `rownum` and `admissoindate`?

Comment: You can use  ORDER BY rownum,TO_DATE(a.admissiondate)

Comment: What database are you using?  Also, please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should learn to use proper `join` syntax.  A simple rule:  Never use commas in the `from` clause.

Second, I don't see `rownum` in any table, so I'll assume you are using Oracle where `rownum` is built-in (this assumption is consistent with the query syntax as well).  The `rownum` value is a sequential value where each row gets its own number.  So:

```
order by rownum, a.admissiondate
```

The second key in the `order by` will never get used.

I think you just want:

```
order by a.admissiondate
```

If you want to order by insertion order into the `icdledger` table (or any other), then you need another column, something like:

```
order by a.admissiondate, a.admissiontime
```

or

```
order by a.admissiondate, a.id
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted by another answer, if you are using the built-in Oracle ROWNUM function, you cannot order by it. It has no meaning except in the final results -- that is, it does not tell you which rows were inserted first, or any other information about the rows in the table.

You will need to change your insert or bulk load procedure to add a ROW_ID or identity column to the table if you want to be able to order the rows based on something that is not in the actual column data.